# Regex search for match words in the file

Tags: python

I am trying to find a regex that can search through the files for a pattern. For example, I try to find the files that contain whitelist(allow_guest=True) ... SELECT...I tried this regex but it didn't work: `(.*whitelist.*allow_guest=True).*SELECT.*` Please see the content below:

```
@frappe.whitelist(allow_guest=True)
def web_search(text, scope=None, start=0, limit=20):
    """
    Search for given text in __global_search where published = 1
    :param text: phrase to be searched
    :param scope: search only in this route, for e.g /docs
    :param start: start results at, default 0
    :param limit: number of results to return, default 20
    :return: Array of result objects
    """

    results = []
    texts = text.split('&')
    for text in texts:
        common_query = ''' SELECT `doctype`, `name`, `content`, `title`, `route`
            FROM `__global_search`
            WHERE {conditions}
            LIMIT {limit} OFFSET {start}'''
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @user5305519: I tried to search here https://github.com/frappe/frappe/archive/refs/tags/v12.12.0.zip all the files that contain the query. The output should show the files that matched.